# Running SQL script in SqlCmd with SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have developed a C# application connecting to a SQL Server database. I now wish to test the application on the client PC, and so I scripted the database and now wish to deploy it on the client PC.

The client PC is running SQL Server Express, however SQL Server Management Studio is not installed and so I thought I would use `SqlCmd` to execute the script on the local server of the PC. Note: when I installed SQL Server Express I set the instance name to `MSSQLSERVER`.

[image]

The problem I'm having is with the command I'm typing :

```
-S SomePCName\MSSQLSERVER -i C:\CreateDBSql.sql
```

When I run the command, I get the following message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you specify the database name in your script? else -d <databasename>

Comment: The script should create a new database. So there is no need to specify the database name.

Comment: What is the full command line that you are running? Why did you specify an instance name? The default instance name for SQL Server Express is `SQLExpress`, but is `MSSQLServer` for the other editions. Also, what do you mean "nothing happens"? How long did you wait? There is a connection timeout and command timeout, so it won't sit there forever.

Comment: I just updated OP. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem mainly appears to be that you are not running **SQLCMD** correctly. Command-line parameters (or "flags" or "switches") need to be entered on the, well, command line ;-).  Try the following (note the use of `(local)`):

```
SQLCMD -S (local)\MSSQLSERVER -i C:\CreateDBSql.sql
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems that since *MSSQLSERVER* is the default "default instance" name, it is reserved and cannot be used in a connection string explicitly. In this case you can try the following:

```
SQLCMD -S (local) -i C:\CreateDBSql.sql
```

If that doesn't work, then it might be best to reinstall SQL Server Express while using a different instance name: either the preferred default instance name for SQL Server Express (i.e. `SQLExpress`) or something that is neither `SQLExpress` nor `MSSQLSERVER`.

Comment: Will this work for express? I heard once that express uses (local) with some additional text? Thank you!

Comment: @MarnusSteyn  Try it and you will see ;-). Yes, it does work and I tried it myself. You are getting confused with the related product: **SQL Server Express LocalDB**, which uses `(localdb)\InstanceName`. `(local)` is the preferred syntax for referring to the local machine for non-LocalDB instances.

Comment: Tried it, and updated the OP. At least I'm one step forward from where i was. I am getting a response now from the server, but it is complaining.

Comment: @MarnusSteyn I added an **UPDATE:** section to my answer with more info.